# The given value is not suitable for module terraform error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I am building a terraform module for a Cloud Native application hosted on AWS to aid in learning both technologies but I run into an error informing me "The given value is not suitable for module terraform error...".

My module is designed as follows:

```
Root
  modules
    Application module (main, vars, output.tf files)
    Network module (main, vars, output.tf files)
    Security module (main, vars, output.tf files)
  main.tf
  vars.tf
  output.tf
```

But I have hit a snag while testing the Application module.

In the network module, I have code for creating an AWS VPC with multiple public subnets.

**network module main.tf**

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnets" {
  for_each   = {for subnet, value in var.public_subnets : subnet => value}
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(var.main_vpc_cidr, 8, index((var.public_subnets), each.value)+1)
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names[index(var.public_subnets, each.value)]
    
  tags = {
    Name        = each.value
    environment = var.environment
  }
}
```

**network module output.tf**

```
output "public_subnets" {
  value = aws_subnet.public_subnets
}
```

**root module main.tf**

```
module "network" {
  source = "./modules/network"
  main_vpc_cidr   = "10.0.0.0/16"
  vpc_name        = "main_vpc"
  environment     = "Testing"
  public_subnets  = ["public_subnet 1", "public_subnet 2"]
  private_subnets = ["private_subnet 1", "private_subnet 2"]
  wildcard        = "0.0.0.0/0"
}
    
module "security" {
  source = "./modules/security"
  wildcard    = "0.0.0.0/0"
  environment = "Testing"
  main_vpc_id = "module.network.vpc_id"
}
    
module "application" {
  source = "./modules/application"
  alb_name       = "nginx-alb"
  environment    = "Testing"
  alb_id         = "module.security.alb_sg"
  public_subnets = "module.network.public_subnets"
  main_vpc_id    = "module.network.vpc_id"
}
```

**application module main.tf**

```
resource "aws_lb" "nginx_alb" {
  name               = var.alb_name
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [var.alb_id]
  subnets = var.public_subnets
    
  tags = {
    environment = var.environment
  }
}
```

**application module vars.tf**

```
variable "public_subnets" {
  type = list(map(any))
}
```

When I run **terraform plan** to test the code, I get the following error

```
    │ Error: Invalid value for input variable
    │ 
    │   on main.tf line 23, in module "application":
    │   23:   public_subnets = "module.network.public_subnets"
    │ 
    │ The given value is not suitable for module.application.var.public_subnets declared at modules/application/vars.tf:13,1-26:
    │ list of map of any single type required.
```

Important to note that I have tried various tweaks to test the code e.g running a for loop on the public_subnets output value to ensure it returns a single string such as

```
[for subnet in aws_subnets.public_subnets: subnet.id]
```

Each time, I get the same error such as

```
     Error: Invalid value for input variable
    │ 
    │   on main.tf line 23, in module "application":
    │   23:   public_subnets = "module.network.public_subnets"
    │ 
    │ The given value is not suitable for module.application.var.public_subnets declared at modules/application/vars.tf:13,1-26:
    │ list of map of string required.
```

For clarity, I have provided the output of the public_subnets obtained via **terraform plan** below:

```
    + public_subnets = [
          + {
              + arn                                            = (known after apply)
              + assign_ipv6_address_on_creation                = false
              + availability_zone                              = "us-east-1a"
              + availability_zone_id                           = (known after apply)
              + cidr_block                                     = "10.0.1.0/24"
              + customer_owned_ipv4_pool                       = null
              + enable_dns64                                   = false
              + enable_lni_at_device_index                     = null
              + enable_resource_name_dns_a_record_on_launch    = false
              + enable_resource_name_dns_aaaa_record_on_launch = false
              + id                                             = (known after apply)
              + ipv6_cidr_block                                = null
              + ipv6_cidr_block_association_id                 = (known after apply)
              + ipv6_native                                    = false
              + map_customer_owned_ip_on_launch                = null
              + map_public_ip_on_launch                        = false
              + outpost_arn                                    = null
              + owner_id                                       = (known after apply)
              + private_dns_hostname_type_on_launch            = (known after apply)
              + tags                                           = {
                  + Name        = "public_subnet 1"
                  + environment = "Testing"
                }
              + tags_all                                       = {
                  + Name        = "public_subnet 1"
                  + environment = "Testing"
                }
              + timeouts                                       = null
              + vpc_id                                         = (known after apply)
            },
          + {
              + arn                                            = (known after apply)
              + assign_ipv6_address_on_creation                = false
              + availability_zone                              = "us-east-1b"
              + availability_zone_id                           = (known after apply)
              + cidr_block                                     = "10.0.2.0/24"
              + customer_owned_ipv4_pool                       = null
              + enable_dns64                                   = false
              + enable_lni_at_device_index                     = null
              + enable_resource_name_dns_a_record_on_launch    = false
              + enable_resource_name_dns_aaaa_record_on_launch = false
              + id                                             = (known after apply)
              + ipv6_cidr_block                                = null
              + ipv6_cidr_block_association_id                 = (known after apply)
              + ipv6_native                                    = false
              + map_customer_owned_ip_on_launch                = null
              + map_public_ip_on_launch                        = false
              + outpost_arn                                    = null
              + owner_id                                       = (known after apply)
              + private_dns_hostname_type_on_launch            = (known after apply)
              + tags                                           = {
                  + Name        = "public_subnet 2"
                  + environment = "Testing"
                }
              + tags_all                                       = {
                  + Name        = "public_subnet 2"
                  + environment = "Testing"
                }
              + timeouts                                       = null
              + vpc_id                                         = (known after apply)
            },
        ]
```

I would really appreciate assistance as i've been stuck on this for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `public_subnets = "module.network.public_subnets"`

Your are assigning a literal string saying "module.network.public_subnets"

Lose the quotes:

> `public_subnets = module.network.public_subnets`

Also note that [`aws_lb.subnets`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb#subnets) is a list of strings, not a list of maps. You should fix the type of `application.subnets` accordingly.

To check the types of your expressions, you can run `terraform console` and use the [`type`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/type) function.

This terraform works and builds a plan:

```
diff --git a/main.tf b/main.tf
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..d522474
--- /dev/null
+++ b/main.tf
@@ -0,0 +1,8 @@
+module "network" {
+  source = "./modules/network"
+}
+
+module "application" {
+  source         = "./modules/application"
+  public_subnets = module.network.public_subnets
+}
diff --git a/modules/application/main.tf b/modules/application/main.tf
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..aa5c42d
--- /dev/null
+++ b/modules/application/main.tf
@@ -0,0 +1,5 @@
+resource "aws_lb" "nginx_alb" {
+  internal           = false
+  load_balancer_type = "application"
+  subnets            = var.public_subnets
+}
diff --git a/modules/application/vars.tf b/modules/application/vars.tf
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..6f187cb
--- /dev/null
+++ b/modules/application/vars.tf
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+variable "public_subnets" {
+  type = list(string)
+}
diff --git a/modules/network/main.tf b/modules/network/main.tf
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..402057b
--- /dev/null
+++ b/modules/network/main.tf
@@ -0,0 +1,4 @@
+resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnets" {
+  for_each = toset(["test"])
+  vpc_id   = "test"
+}
diff --git a/modules/network/outpuf.tf b/modules/network/outpuf.tf
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..9eed5a3
--- /dev/null
+++ b/modules/network/outpuf.tf
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+output "public_subnets" {
+  value = [for subnet in aws_subnet.public_subnets : subnet.id]
+}
diff --git a/providers.tf b/providers.tf
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..12ae8b8
--- /dev/null
+++ b/providers.tf
@@ -0,0 +1,4 @@
+
+provider "aws" {
+  region = "us-east-1"
+}
```

If I put the quotes back, it gives me the same exact error as you are getting.

Comment: Made the suggested changes but the issue persists


│ Error: Invalid value for input variable
│ 
│   on main.tf line 23, in module "application":
│   23:   public_subnets = module.network.public_subnets
│ 
│ The given value is not suitable for module.application.var.public_subnets declared at modules/application/vars.tf:13,1-26:
│ list of string required.
╵

Comment: @Rippyblogger: check the type of `module.network.public_subnets` (see the update). Earlier you mentioned "running a for loop on the public_subnets output value to ensure it returns a single string". You need to do the opposite of that: make sure it does not return a single string, but a list of strings. Have you since reverted it?

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your help.
So let me start by saying with regard to assigning a literal string, that is absolutely not the issue/reason why this error occurs. The result does not change either way and i have tested other modules using this convention **public_subnets = "module.network.public_subnets"**.


2. i have in the past indeed checked the type using terraform console. It comes out as **dynamic**.  Hence why i tried using the for loop to ensure only the id is added to the output as a list but the issue persists.

Comment: @Rippyblogger: sorry man, I don't know what else to tell you. I just checked it on my machine, when I put the quotes there, it shows me the same error; when I remove the quotes, the error goes away and the plan builds. See the update.

Comment: Apologies. Appears i was wrong and forgot to save my latest changes. This indeed solves the issue. Thank you for your patience.